# Select dynamic properties OData

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I have problem trying to select dynamically created property using OData 4.0 and .net core. I can filter, group, sum etc, but just can't select fields. Here is a json sample that my API is trying to parse:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "value": 1,
    "details": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "value": 2,
    "details": {
        "field1": 2,
        "field2": "bar"
    }
}]
```

I tried the following syntaxes to select only "field1":

- **[url]/?$select=details**. Got: "[" as return
- **[url]/?$select=details/field1**. Got: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. A path within the select or expand query option is not supported." as return
- **[url]/?$expand=details($select=field1)**. Got: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'details' on type 'ProductDiscovery.DTO.GenericResponse'." as return
- **[url]/?$select=field1**. Got "The query specified in the URI is not valid. A path within the select or expand query option is not supported." as return

The API is implemented in .net core 2.2, using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData v5.70 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Odata v7.2.2. I created a class called "GenericReponse" that is responsible to deserialize the response:

```
public class GenericResponse
{
    [Key]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> details { get; set; }
}
```

This is my EdmModel:

```
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";

        builder.EntitySet<DTO.GenericResponse>("GenericResponse");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

Also tried:

```
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();
        ComplexTypeConfiguration<DTO.GenericResponse> genericResponse = 
        builder.ComplexType<DTO.GenericResponse>();
        genericResponse.Property(g => g.name);
        genericResponse.Property(g => g.value);
        genericResponse .HasDynamicProperties(g => g.details);
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

But got the same results

Thats my controller. I'm curretly mocking two endpoints with json responses:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("filters/odata/queryEnabled/testPolimorfismo")]
    public async Task<IQueryable> BulkRequest8(string port)
    {
        string url1 = @"http://localhost:3000/test"; 
        string url2 = @"http://localhost:4000/test";
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response1 = client.GetAsync(url1).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<DTO.GenericResponse>().Result;            
        var response2 = client.GetAsync(url2).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<DTO.GenericResponse>().Result;
        List<DTO.GenericResponse> responseList = new List<GenericResponse>();
        responseList.Add(response1);
        responseList.Add(response2);
        return responseList.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Any suggestions to solve this error?

Comment: I think you are missing questionmark in your url. Something like [url]/?$select=field1 should work fine. [Query by dynamic properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/query-by-dynamic-properties)

Comment: Also I think you don't need `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData` package.

Comment: Sorry i just missed de question mark. I'm using postman to make these calls and it automatically places question mark. I will edit my original post

Comment: You were right about Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData package. I removed it and the code kept working the same way. Unfortnatelly, the problem with select persists.

Comment: I have tried it, but with no success. To me it seems like select works, but there is an issue with serializing as in response you can see start of an array and then something crashes and response is closed. I have not much time to investigate further today. You can try to create custom formatter to investigate if at least selected data are okay. [Custom OData formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/customize-formatter).